# what is angular frequency ! what does it mean?

Tags: signal-analysis

I know that

$$ \omega = 2 \pi f $$

why do we use angular freq to expression about the instantaneous values of the wave?

Comment: The instantaneous values of the wave are governed by the *phase*, not the frequency.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47042/very-basic-question-about-how-we-define-frequency-in-signal-processing/47108#47108).

Comment: What angular frequency means in simple words . I can define the simple frequency by number of cycles per second I am asking about the physical meaning !

Comment: Did you read my answer?  Do you know what radians are?  Between this and your other question, it seems that you need to understand the sine and cosine functions a little bit better as a start.

Comment: So could you  recommend any good materials to me I will be so thankful for your help

Comment: A little searching on the internet is your easiest option.  For instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves) was found with a search on "basic signal radians".  Sines and cosines can be found in math books under Trigonometry (three side measurements), but that covers a lot more than what you need to know to model a pure tone signal.  Simply put, radians are the natural measure for angles whereas degrees are an arbitrary measure.  Radians are the best choice when doing mathematics, particularly when Calculus gets involved.  Degrees are handy for every day use.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to understand with units.  The argument for the sine and cosine functions are in radians.  Thus angular velocity represents the frequency in the most convenient way for these functions.  For instance, if your time unit is seconds, then the units for $f$ are cycles per second, aka Hz.  The $2\pi$ has units of radians per cycle, so the equation you mentioned $ \omega = 2 \pi f $ has units of:

$$ \frac{radians}{second} = \frac{radians}{cycle} \cdot \frac{cycles}{second} $$

When it is plugged into the equation for your signal:

$$ s(t) = A \cos( \omega t + \phi ) $$

The argument $ \omega t + \phi $ has units of:

$$ \frac{radians}{second} \cdot seconds + radians = radians $$

Hope this helps.

Ced

Comment: radians as "units" is maybe not the best expression.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I'm baffled by you saying that.  A radian is a unit distance along the circumference of a unit circle on the same scale as the underlying Cartesian coordinates.  It can also be used as an angle measurement for the angle that subtends that arc.  Why is "unit" not a very good description of that?

Comment: angles expressed (or measured) in radians are dimensionless numbers.  **pure** numbers.  meaning no units attached.  for a circle of radius $r$, when an arc of length $s$ is swept, $\theta$ is simply the ratio, the dimensionless constant of proportionality relating $s$ and $r$:  $$ s = r \theta $$  $s$ is in units of length, $r$ is in unis of length, and $\theta$ is simply the dimensionless number that scales $r$ to equal $s$.  degree is not really unit, but simply a dimensionless constant.  attaching the degree symbol "°" is simply multiplying by the pure number $\frac{\pi}{180}$.

Comment: **nepers** are not units either and neither are **decibels**.  the **dB** "unit" has the same kind of role that the degree symbol ° has.  attaching *"dB"* to a quantity is simply multiplying that quantity by $\frac{\log(10)}{20}$. $$ $$ likewise **percent** is not a unit.  attaching the "%" symbol is the same as scaling by the dimensionless constant $\frac{1}{100}$.  that's all it is.

Comment: i guess we can consider the number $1$ as the unit for integers and for real numbers and the number $i$ (or just as legitimately $-i$) as the unit for imaginary numbers.  would that mean the number $2$ is the *"unit"* for even numbers?

Comment: this is **not** the same as the conversion factor between two dimensionful quantities of the *same* dimension expressed in different units.  e.g. for length, the number 1609.344 is meaningless.  it's just a number.  but this number:

$$ 1609.344 \ \frac{\text{meters}}{\text{mile}} $$

is not meaningless for human systems of measurement in our present time.  and that dimensionless quantity above is equal to the number $1$.

Comment: [looks like others have discussed this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418744/are-radians-degrees-and-gradians-not-units).  i like the [laerne](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252762/l%C3%A6rne) comment the best.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, Thanks for all the replies.  I've been down this path before.  Units aren't the same as dimensions.  I refute you thus: "The International System of Units assigns special names to 22 derived units, which includes two dimensionless derived units, the radian (rad) and the steradian (sr)."  from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit.  Conversion factors, which convert from one unit to a different unit in the same dimension, are by definition dimensionless.  A cycle is dimensionless and a radian is dimensionless, yet 2*Pi is still the conversion factor.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Saying that radian is not a unit is saying you cannot measure angles. It's preposterous. Yes, it's dimensionless, but it's still a unit. Using your own logic, 2.43 is meaningless, but 2.43 radian is not meaningless.

Comment: One needs to distinguish  radians from degrees from revolutions from laps from orbits from rings around the Rosie.  The term unit seems to have that function. If there is a better term that would be nice but I don’t think there is